# get latitude and longitude with geocoder and android Google Maps API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, android-maps-v2

I'm using the Google Maps API v2 for android and works properly.
However, I am trying to use geocoder to get the longitude and latitude of an address, but without success.

It has changed the way to do it from the v2?

I am using the conventional code

```
Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(context);
//...
  List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName("1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA", 1);

  Address address = list.get(0);

  double lat = address.getLatitude();
  double lng = address.getLongitude();
//...
```

Always returns a forced shutdown, and Log solves nothing.
When using a block of try / catch, opens the map but always with the same location
Use the Internet permission, I have included in the project also COARSE_LOCATION
I have used various codes located here and on other sites, but without success.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you have android.permission.INTERNET permission set?

Comment: You say log solves nothing, maybe you should include it anyway (I bet it actually does have some clues on what is wrong).

Comment: I have the internet permission, logs, thanks:03-29 22:25:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(4359): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{blue.ninja.master/blue.ninja.master.Hola}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 22:25:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(4359):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-29 22:25:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(4359):  at android.app.ActivityThread
03-29 22:25:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(4359): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 22:25:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(4359):  at blue.ninja.master.Hola.onCreate(Hola.java:50)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try this solution using this example url:

> http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=mumbai&sensor=false

which returns data in `json` format with `lat/lng` of `address`.

```
private class DataLongOperationAsynchTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
   ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        String response;
        try {
            response = getLatLongByURL("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=mumbai&sensor=false");
            Log.d("response",""+response);
            return new String[]{response};
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new String[]{"error"};
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String... result) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result[0]);

            double lng = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                    .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                    .getDouble("lng");

            double lat = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                    .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                    .getDouble("lat");

            Log.d("latitude", "" + lat);
            Log.d("longitude", "" + lng);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}


public String getLatLongByURL(String requestURL) {
    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;
            }
        } else {
            response = "";
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: @AmolSawant96Kuli is this solution working fine? I ask you because I see that Geocoder doesn't work well...

Comment: Is it client-side geocoding or server-side? Unfortunately I am unable to find the difference in code because there is no proper example out there.

Comment: Can you please update the code? It seems HttpClient is deprecated and isn't available on Android 6 anymore.

Comment: @android developer, Thanks for updating. I updated my code as per new new Android version 6.

Comment: @AmolSawant96Kuli Thank you. Say, is it really ok to use Google's website this way? No need to register for them or something?

Comment: I think you should also use Uri.Builder instead of a constant string, so that it should automatically replace the characters as needed.

Comment: Here. this is better for the URL creation: String queryUrl = new Uri.Builder().scheme("http").authority("maps.google.com").appendPath("maps").appendPath("api").appendPath("geocode")
                .appendPath("json").appendQueryParameter("address", query).appendQueryParameter("sensor", "false").build().toString();

Comment: Does this code still work for you?  I'm getting a network timeout and 0 results.  The alternatives to this solution are pretty ugly, so I'm really hoping this can still work for me.

Answer (score 8):

Try this out.

```
private void getLatLongFromAddress(String address)
{
    double lat= 0.0, lng= 0.0;

    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());    
    try 
    {
        List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(address , 1);
        if (addresses.size() > 0) 
        {            
            GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                    (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));

            lat=p.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
            lng=p.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;

            Log.d("Latitude", ""+lat);
            Log.d("Longitude", ""+lng);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: seems that the problem is a bug of android: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816  ...I do not know how to fix it :(((

Comment: @MiguelC : Could you find LatLng using address? Am facing same problem.

Comment: I find that for me the results are always in the wrong country (even if I include the country in the address).

Answer (score 2):

since the HttpClient has been depreciated, you may try the following code with Asynctask (also note that we need to encode the address into URL) :

```
public class GeoCoding extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private String address;
    private static final String TAG = GeoCoding.class.getSimpleName();
    JSONObject jsonObj;
    String URL;
    private String Address1 = "", Address2 = "", City = "", State = "", Country = "", County = "", PIN = "", Area="";
    private  double latitude, longitude;
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    BufferedReader br;
    StringBuilder sb ;

    public GeoCoding(String address){
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getArea(){
        return Area;
    }

    public void getAddress() {
        Address1 = "";
        Address2 = "";
        City = "";
        State = "";
        Country = "";
        County = "";
        PIN = "";
        Area ="";

        try {

            String Status = jsonObj.getString("status");
            if (Status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {
                JSONArray Results = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");
                JSONObject zero = Results.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONArray address_components = zero.getJSONArray("address_components");

                for (int i = 0; i < address_components.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject zero2 = address_components.getJSONObject(i);
                    String long_name = zero2.getString("long_name");
                    JSONArray mtypes = zero2.getJSONArray("types");
                    String Type = mtypes.getString(0);

                    if (! TextUtils.isEmpty(long_name) || !long_name.equals(null) || long_name.length() > 0 || !long_name.equals("")) {
                        if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("street_number")) {
                            Address1 = long_name + " ";
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("route")) {
                            Address1 = Address1 + long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("sublocality")) {
                            Address2 = long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("locality")) {
                            City = long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("administrative_area_level_2")) {
                            County = long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("administrative_area_level_1")) {
                            State = long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("country")) {
                            Country = long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("postal_code")) {
                            PIN = long_name;
                        }else if( Type.equalsIgnoreCase("neighborhood")){
                            Area = long_name;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public void getGeoPoint(){
        try{
             longitude = ((JSONArray)jsonObj.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                    .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                    .getDouble("lng");
            latitude = ((JSONArray)jsonObj.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                    .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                    .getDouble("lat");

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)  {
        try {
            StringBuilder urlStringBuilder = new StringBuilder("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json");
            urlStringBuilder.append("?address=" + URLEncoder.encode(address, "utf8"));
            urlStringBuilder.append("&sensor=false");
            URL = urlStringBuilder.toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "URL: " + URL);

            URL url = new URL(URL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb = sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "response code: " + connection.getResponseCode());
            jsonObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "JSON obj: " + jsonObj);
            getAddress();
            Log.d(TAG, "area is: " + getArea());
            getGeoPoint();
            Log.d("latitude", "" + latitude);
            Log.d("longitude", "" + longitude);


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple rectification that worked for me is to just enable the internet connection on the device. Suggestion by [Pxaml](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8765409/pxaml).

Answer (score -11):

you can get latitude and longitude of current location by this simple code

```
GPS_Location mGPS = new GPS_Location(MyApplication.getAppContext());

    if (mGPS.canGetLocation) {

        mLat = mGPS.getLatitude();
        mLong = mGPS.getLongitude();

    } else {
        System.out.println("cannot find");
    }
```

You must add gps and other permissions to your app