# Get Lat, Long from address

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I want to get the latitude and longitude by entering the address,
the following code i copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711499/get-latitude-and-longitude-with-geocoder-and-android-google-maps-api-v2/15747491#15747491) but in my case while i am passing full address its giving me error:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 56: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=43 S BROADWAY, Pitman, New Jersey`.

```
public static void getLatLongFromAddress(String youraddress) {
    String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +
                  youraddress + "&sensor=false";
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        int b;
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());

        double lng = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
            .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
            .getDouble("lng");

        dobule lat = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
            .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
            .getDouble("lat");

        Log.d("latitude", lat);
        Log.d("longitude", lng);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use below online tool to get lat and long from address
https://www.workversatile.com/convert-address-to-lat-long

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass a space to a URL. 
Try to replace every space with `%20` and you should be fine to go.

```
String replaced = yourString.replace(" ", "%20");
```

Further information: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

[Characters allowed in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url)

[How do I replace a character in a string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234510/how-do-i-replace-a-character-in-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Use :

```
youraddress = youraddress.replaceAll("\\s", "+");
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +
              youraddress + "&sensor=false";
```

Replace all spaces to +, similar to the way google does. This is how we are using in our apps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the current city or location reference from address any field name form address string and then you get the lat and lng like

```
`Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault()); List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);`
```

Please try this:

```
private static JSONObject getLocationInfo(String address)
{

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {

    address = address.replaceAll(" ","%20");    

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&sensor=false");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


        response = client.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        int b;
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.i("getLocationInfo ClientProtocolException", e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {

        Log.i("getLocationInfo IOException", e.toString());
    }


    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.i("getLocationInfo JSONException", e.toString());
    }

    return jsonObject;
}

private static boolean getLatLong(JSONObject jsonObject) 
{

    try {

       longitute = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lng");
        Log.i("Log1", longitute1+"");
    latitude = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
            .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
            .getDouble("lat");
        Log.i("lat1", latitude1+"");
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        longitute=0;
        latitude = 0;
        Log.i("getLatLong", e.toString());
        return false;

    }

    return true;
}
```

or further geocode need you :

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
if (addresses.size() > 0) 
    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: What have you changed? The point of SO is that other people with the same problem as the OP can reproduce and fix it. With a fixed code without explanation this is really hard to do.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.htmlplease specified here

Comment: you need to specified the current city or location reference from address any field name form address string and then you get the lat and lng like Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);

Answer (score 0):

Should encode "youraddress" like

```
String encodedYourAddress = URLEncoder.encode(youraddress, "UTF-8");
```

and build the called URI as

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+encodedYourAddress+"&sensor=false";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for that

```
public LatLng getLatLng(Context _context,String locn){
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(_context,Locale.getDefault());
        try{                
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locn, 5);
            if(addresses.size()>0)
            {                   
                GeoPoint p=new GeoPoint((int)(addresses.get(0).getLatitude()*1E6),(int)(addresses.get(0).getLongitude()*1E6));
                Double plat= (double) (p.getLatitudeE6())/1E6;
                Double plon =(double) (p.getLongitudeE6())/1E6;
                LatLng lonlat=new LatLng(plat,plon);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lonlat;          
    }
```

Just pass the current `context` and the address as `String` that has to be converted to `LatLng`.The above function will return the `LatLng` value of the address.

And, You can get the corresponding Latitude and Longitude values as follows

```
double lat = lonlat.latitude;
double lng = lonlat.longitude;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've same problem once. I figured it out using URLEncoder class.

I think you should encode your search term and put it in url like,

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode(address, "utf-8");
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
                        + query + "&ka&sensor=false");
```

this is the best solution as per my understanding working for me.